# django pytest not working as expected

Tags: django, pytest

I'm trying to use pytest-django. I think it is correctly installed:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade pytest-django
Requirement already up-to-date: pytest-django in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
```

However:

```
py.test --ds myproj.settings_module
usage: py.test [options] [file_or_dir] [file_or_dir] [...]
py.test: error: unrecognized arguments: --ds
```

what's the problem? How can I check that django-pytest is installed?

*more info*

```
$ which py.test
/usr/local/bin/py.test
$ py.test --version
This is pytest version 2.5.2, imported from /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pytest.pyc
```

*more info (2)*

```
$ which python
/usr/bin/python
$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jan  2 2013, 16:53:07) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import pytest_django
>>> 
$ py.test --traceconfig
PLUGIN registered: <_pytest.python.FixtureManager instance at 0x8fa0d6c>
======================================================================== test session starts =========================================================================
platform linux2 -- Python 2.7.3 -- py-1.4.20 -- pytest-2.5.2
using: pytest-2.5.2 pylib-1.4.20
active plugins:
    helpconfig          : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/helpconfig.pyc
    pytestconfig        : <_pytest.config.Config object at 0x8ce0f6c>
    runner              : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/runner.pyc
    unittest            : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/unittest.pyc
    pastebin            : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/pastebin.pyc
    skipping            : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/skipping.pyc
    genscript           : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/genscript.pyc
    session             : <Session 'delme'>
    tmpdir              : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/tmpdir.pyc
    capture             : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/capture.pyc
    terminalreporter    : <_pytest.terminal.TerminalReporter instance at 0x8df44cc>
    assertion           : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/assertion/__init__.pyc
    mark                : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/mark.pyc
    terminal            : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/terminal.pyc
    main                : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/main.pyc
    nose                : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/nose.pyc
    python              : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/python.pyc
    146879340           : <_pytest.config.PytestPluginManager object at 0x8c1336c>
    recwarn             : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/recwarn.pyc
    funcmanage          : <_pytest.python.FixtureManager instance at 0x8fa0d6c>
    monkeypatch         : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/monkeypatch.pyc
    resultlog           : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/resultlog.pyc
    capturemanager      : <_pytest.capture.CaptureManager instance at 0x8df972c>
    junitxml            : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/junitxml.pyc
    doctest             : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/doctest.pyc
    pdb                 : /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/_pytest/pdb.pyc
collected 0 items 

==========================================================================  in 0.00 seconds ==========================================================================
```

Comment: Have you set `TEST_RUNNER = 'django_pytest.test_runner.TestRunner'` and added `django_pytest` to the `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: no... should I put that in the settings?

Comment: Oops, nope, it's a different package you are using, sorry, not relevant.

Comment: Are you saying that django-pytest and pytest-django are different projects?

Comment: Yup, see [django-pytest](https://github.com/buchuki/django-pytest) and  [pytest_django](https://github.com/pelme/pytest_django).

Comment: Are you using virtual environments? What's the result of `which py.test`?

Comment: $ which py.test
/usr/local/bin/py.test

Comment: no virtual environment...

Comment: `py.test --version` should show pytest-django as installed.  Since it doesn't there's something wrong with the paths used somewhere.  It may be easiest to try and re-create this in a brand new virtualenv.

Answer (score 2):

The py.test documentation recommends using `py.test --traceconfig` to determine what plugins are installed. (Source: http://pytest.org/latest/plugins.html#finding-out-which-plugins-are-active)

As a sanity check, I would make sure you can import `pytest_django` at a Python prompt.

```
$ which python
// Expect this to be /usr/local/bin/python
$ python
>>> import pytest_django
```

At the very least, you are working with two versions of Python between your initial question and your "more information (2)" section. Notice how first the paths begin with `/usr/local/lib/python2.6/` and then later they begin with `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/`? This is pretty weird, and a mismatch like this may explain why you can import `pytest_django` and yet `py.test` isn't seeing the plugin installed.

I recommend using `virtualenv` if at all possible to side-step environment issues like this.
Here is a good tutorial about how to get started: http://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/how-to-use-python-virtualenv

Try this:

```
sudo pip install virtualenv
virtualenv env --no-site-packages --python=python2.6  // Can be python2.7 too.
source env/bin/activate
pip install pytest-django  // Should pull in Django and pytest dependencies.
py.test --traceconfig
```

Comment: I've added more information (2) in the question. import pytest_django finds the package, but --traceconfig does not list anything related to django.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hopefully using `virtualenv` is a possibility for your use case, otherwise we can keep digging.

Comment: Yes, with virtualenv it seems to work! I get an error message because it does not find my django settings. But: is it not possible to *not* use virtualenv?

Comment: What is the error message and traceback you get regarding your django settings?

Comment: File "/mydir/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pytest_django/plugin.py", line 76, in _load_settings
    from django.conf import settings
ImportError: No module named django.conf

Comment: You probably do not have Django installed in your virtualenv. Notice that pytest-django has a dependency on pytest but not django. When you use the `--no-site-packages` option, the virtualenv's version of python will not look globally for installed packages. This lets you avoid version conflicts.